# angular 2 http:// and https:// routes

Tags: http, angular, https, routes, router

There is an Angular 2 based application with two routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    }
];
```

The "/home" route should go to "http://mysite/home" and "/login" should go to "https://mysite/login". Please pay attention the first one starts with "http://" and the second one starts with "https://". How is it possible to configure the router to use different origins for routes? Or at least http / https for the same origin?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something particular to Angular2. The routing takes whatever the schema is from the URL when you load the application. You have a couple of options to get the login to require HTTPs.

- Always load the app over HTTPs. Not a bad practice in general, and many web applications do that nowdays.
- Use a re-write plugin for your web server (mod-rewrite for Apache, or IIS rewrite for IIS) to redirect all HTTP requests for the /login route to HTTPs.

Comment: thank you for your response. I would be happy to run all the site over https, but my site can contain references for unsecure resources. For example a page can have <img src="http://example.com/pic.jpg"></img>. In this case the browser will show warnings about unsecure resources referenced from a secure page. Is it possible to get rid off those warnings?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you have to configure something on the backend to re-write your HTTP requests to HTTPs requests. You can use the same methods I mentioned to re-write all requests. Or here is a module I have used under IIS that does the same things. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7206/Switching-Between-HTTP-and-HTTPS-Automatically-Ver